# How can one create a org.eclipse.jface.preference.BooleanFieldEditor with a multi-line label?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, preference

The ff. does not work.  "Second line" is rendered on the same line as "First line".  What's more is that there is no space between the two.

```
new BooleanFieldEditor("Name", "First line\nSecond line", getFieldEditorParent());
```

Comment: Is there an example of this being done in Eclipse? I can't see one and the docs don't indicate it can be done.

Comment: You're right.  I can't find one either.  I just wondered if it could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BooleanFieldEditor uses an SWT Label. You can't specify multiple lines for this type of widget.

I would suggest that you will need to create a custom implementation by subclassing FieldEditor.

Two things to help with this:

- [The source for the BooleanFieldEditor](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/preference/BooleanFieldEditor.java.htm)
- [A tutorial on creating a custom FieldEditor](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Field-Editors/field_editors.html#writing)